# Echo statement in PHP not executing in a specific manner

Tags: php, sql, wampserver

I'm having a problem with some specific PHP code that I've been working on for a few days. It's meant to be a reporting code where I can input a day and a month and it will list the total sales of that particular day.

But, I can't seem to make the last statement whereby, if there are no values(there are no data) in the query, it will display 'No Sales on this particular day'. Here's the code I've been working on. But the last echo statement is not executing. Any ideas?

```
    <?php
  session_start();
  if ((isset($_SESSION["admin"])) ){
   $day=@$_POST['day'];
   $month=@$_POST['month'];
  echo "<center><h2>Sales report on " .$day. "." .$month. ".2013</h2></center>";

    echo "<center><table style='border:2px solid black;' align=center width=600>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan=12><center><h2>Sales Report</h2><hr size='2' color='black' /></center></th></tr>";
    echo " <th width=400> Amount Collected</th>";
    ?>              
              <br> 
               <?php
$x = 1; //counter
//open a connection to a MySQL server using function mysql_connect 
//returns a MySQL link identifier on success, or FALSE on failure.
$conn= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$conn)
    die ("Connection error: ".mysql_error());
else {
    //select a MySQL database
    //returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failurue.
    $db=mysql_select_db("cqfos");
    if(!$db)
        die ("DB not found: ".mysql_error());
    else {
        //put query in a variable $query
        $query= "select ROUND(sum(orderdetails.tprice),2)
                 from orders JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderID = orderdetails.orderID WHERE DAY(orders.date) = '$day' AND MONTH(orders.date) = '$month'";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        if(!$result)
            die ("Invalid query: ".mysql_error());
        //if record exists
        else {
            //fetch a result row as both associative array and numeric array
                if(mysql_num_rows($result)== 1){
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td align='center'>RM ".$row[0]."</td></tr>";  
                    $x++; //increase the counter
                    }
                    }
                else {
                    echo "<tr><th colspan=12>No sales made.</td></tr>";}



                }
             }
        }

echo"</table></center>";

?>
```

Comment: `mysql_num_rows($result)` is not `== 1`

Comment: instead of else{if()} you should use elseif(){}

Comment: @djot well i've tried changing the value, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans will try that method... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems here
your HTML table syntax is incorrect, and your using an old sql library - and it dose not look like your SQL syntax is right... try this code (not tested as I don't have your data)

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if ((isset($_SESSION["admin"])) ){
   echo '<div style="margin:auto; textalign:center;">';
   echo "<h2>Sales report on " .$_POST['day']. "." .$_POST['month']. ".2013</h2>";
   echo "<h2>Sales Report</h2>"
   echo "<table style='border:2px solid black;' align=center width=600>";
   echo "<tr><th width=400> Amount Collected</th></tr>";
   ?>              
   <br> 
   <?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","cqfos");///use mysqli, not mysql : mysql is depricated
if ($conn->mysqli)
  exit ("Connection error: ".$conn->errno ." : " $conn->error);
else {
    //put query in a variable $query
    $eDay = $conn->mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['day']);//escape these to protect the database
    $eMonth = $conn->mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']);;//escape these to protect the database
    //your column name is probably not a rounded value, replaced it with * (return all columns)
    $query= "select * from orders JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderID = orderdetails.orderID WHERE DAY(orders.date) = '"
    .$eDay."' AND MONTH(orders.date) = '".$eMonth."'";

    $result=$con->query($query);
    if($conn->errno)
      exit ("Invalid query: ".$conn->errno ." : " $conn->error);
        //if record exists
    else {
      $numericArray = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);     //fetch a result row as numeric array
      $associativeArray = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); //fetch as an associtive array this is not used, just an example
      $bothArray = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH); //both associtive and numeric this is not used, just an example
    }
    if(!empty($numericArray))
    {
      foreach ($numericArray as $value) {
        echo "<tr><td>RM ".$value[0]."</td><tr>";//is there more then 1 col? if not you should consider an html list
      }
    } else {
      echo "<tr><td>No sales made</td><tr>";
    }
    echo"</table></center>";
  }

    ?>
```

Comment: i'm having an error at line "if ($conn->mysqli)", and when i execute the system, it states, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\CQFOS-Admin\report_sales1.php on line 62 "

Comment: @RayLight incorrect line endings and gremlins(invisible charicters caused by changes in charicter encodings) often cause T_ errors, try changing your line endings to UNIX and set your editor to show invisible charicters

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL (likely) returns more than only one row, so change the line I mentioned before to this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
```

Comment: nope, there are no changes. i even tried to expand the coding with,

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH)){
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td align='center'>RM ".$row[0]."</td></tr>";  
     $x++; //increase the counter
     }
     }
    elseif(mysql_num_rows($result)<0) {
     echo "<tr><th colspan=12>No sales made.</td></tr>";}

Answer (score 0):

Just letting you know your code is vulnerable to SQLi because you have not sanitized $day and $month. Also [please consider using PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

If you haven't already - Try running the SQL statement into PHPMyAdmin and see where it outputs the error (if there is one), else it will output the data.*

*Manually inputting the day/month substituting for the variables.